# Trying to add two linked lists together but getting an AttributeError

Tags: python

I am trying to add two LinkedLists together but I keep receiving an error saying:

`AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'val'`

I understand my code may be wrong algorithmically, but I cannot get around this one error. I have tried removing the `.val` but that throws a different error and I have printed `l1.val` and `l2.val` before the while loop and it prints without error. The following is the definition for the `LinkedList` class provided and my code.

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode(object):
#     def __init__(self, x):
#         self.val = x
#         self.next = None

class Solution(object):
    def addTwoNumbers(self, l1, l2):
        """
        :type l1: ListNode
        :type l2: ListNode
        :rtype: ListNode
        """
        output = ListNode(None)
        while l1:
            temp = l1.val + l2.val
            if temp > 9:
                temp -= 10
                l1 = l1.next.val + 1
            else:
                l1 = l1.next
            output.next = temp
            l2 = l2.next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`temp` is an `int`, but you assign it to `output.next`, which will cause the error you see when it is used as a `ListNode`.

Comment: `output.val = temp`?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I understand now. Thanks.